# Gtk_widget.set_sensitive() not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk

Following is my code, where I am using two radio buttons to activate and deactivate a Gtk.Box type area. The problem I am facing is, it only works for a single time i.e, once I activated the Gtk.Box now I can't deactivate again.

```
def on_toggling_hash_tab_radio_button_1(self, widget):
    self.hash_tab_hbox.set_sensitive(False)        

def on_toggling_hash_tab_radio_button_2(self, widget):
    self.hash_tab_hbox.set_sensitive(True)
```

I have search around a little bit and come to know about Gtk.main() loop and I don't know about it properly. How can I achive this and a little knowledge about main looping would be appreciated.

Thank you

~Shantanu Kumar

Answer (score 1):

> When an unselected button in the group is clicked the clicked button receives the “toggled” signal, as does the previously selected button. Inside the “toggled” handler, gtk_toggle_button_get_active() can be used to determine if the button has been selected or deselected.

Simple example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Example")

        self.main_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.box_area = Gtk.Box(margin=18)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label="Gtk.Box area")
        self.box_area.add(self.label)
        self.box_area.set_sensitive(False)
        self.radio_button_1 = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label(None, "Deactive")
        self.radio_button_2 = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(self.radio_button_1, "Active")
        self.radio_button_1.connect("toggled", self.on_radio_button_1_toggled)
        self.main_box.add(self.box_area)
        self.main_box.add(self.radio_button_1)
        self.main_box.add(self.radio_button_2)
        self.add(self.main_box)

    def on_radio_button_1_toggled(self, widget):
        if self.radio_button_1.get_active() == True:
            self.box_area.set_sensitive(False)
        else:
            self.box_area.set_sensitive(True)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The same effect can be obtained more simply by binding the properties of objects:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Example")

        self.main_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.box_area = Gtk.Box(margin=18)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label="Gtk.Box area")
        self.box_area.add(self.label)
        self.box_area.set_sensitive(False)
        self.radio_button_1 = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label(None, "Deactive")
        self.radio_button_2 = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(self.radio_button_1, "Active")
        self.radio_button_1.bind_property("active", self.box_area, "sensitive", GObject.BindingFlags.INVERT_BOOLEAN)
        self.main_box.add(self.box_area)
        self.main_box.add(self.radio_button_1)
        self.main_box.add(self.radio_button_2)
        self.add(self.main_box)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Your second solution worked for me, your first solution is same as of mine and not working for me (may be because of some other bugs) , but second one was such a clever idea. I am so grateful to you.